# VS2010 C# Form not showing Dirty

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a few forms in a project that don't show to be 'Dirty' after adding a component or control.  This is causing the form to not save the Designer.cs file.  After closing the form and re-opening the new controls are lost.  This doesn't happen on all forms, so I know it is form specific.  Any thoughts?

Comment: you can't catch VS2010 C# Form showing dirty.

Comment: Could you be more precise on the topic? How do you add new components to your form? Is there a difference when you add a standard component and when you add a user control?

Comment: I am adding components or controls using the designer.  There is not a difference in adding a component or a control.  These forms were working before, but seem to have quit for some reason.

Comment: I'm not trying to 'Catch' it.  When I make a change to certain forms I don't get the red dot next to the filename on the tab indicating that the file has changed.  Therefore when I try to save it doesn't think it needs to.

Comment: @ChuckD, have you modified the cs file behind the designer manually for those forms? It might be a reason.

Comment: Youenn - I don't believe that is the problem.  I have now been able to trace the problem to any form containing a particular user control.  It is strange that it changes the way the form is behaving.

Comment: The more typical explanation for a problem like this is your code throwing exceptions at design time.  Debug this by starting another instance of VS and use Tools + Attach to Process to attach it to the first.  Debug + Exceptions, tick Thrown for CLR exceptions to catch them.

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but have you checked the warnings generated? If you open the `Errors` tab and make sure warnings are visible, check to see if there is a line saying (something like, I don't have VS in front of me) "Generation of design file cannot take place because...". I know I've had problems with badly formed or unknown ascx control references

Comment: @Hans - I wasn't able to catch any errors.

Comment: @freefaller I'm not seeing any warnings either.

Comment: if you are adding user controls, make sure that you add controls after you build them.